# List index out of range in Python menu

Tags: python

I am trying to write a menu that will read a system from the user. I managed to make the code for the input of the matrices work, and the menu itself, but when I try to put them together I keep getting an error message although they work separately.

This is what I have so far:

```
ans=True
while ans:
    print ("""
    1) First part
    2) Second part
    3) Third part
    4) Fourth part
    """)
    ans=input("Choose option ") 
    if ans=="1": 
      n = int(input("Number of variables: "))
      matriz_A=[]
      for i in range(n):
        b=[]
        for j in range(n):
          j=float(input("Type entry ["+str(i+1)+"]["+str(j+1)+"] of matriz A: "))
        b.append(j)
        matriz_A.append(b)
        for i in  range(n):
          for j in range(n):
           print('[', end=" ")
          for j in range(n):
            print(matriz_A[i][j],end=" ")
          print(']', end="")
          if i != n-1:
            print()
            print(']')
```

Before I was struggling with the indentation, but now the error message tells me that the list index is out of range.

Where am I making the mistake while putting the two codes together (menu and matrix) since they work fine on their own?

Comment: Apart from indentation, you are using the same variable name `i` for nested loops.

Comment: use 4 spaces for each level of indentation, it will be much more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there  might be many things causing the error, one of the rason might be using the same looping variable for in the nested loop, it is advised to use a different looping variable in each nest.
the other point you are assigning values to your looping variable in

```
for j in range(n):
          j=float(input("Type entry ["+str(i+1)+"]["+str(j+1)+"] of matriz A: "))
```

you may need to use a different variable to assign there.

Also you may try to use a sublime text to check if your indentation is correct